# What is the order of evaluation in below code written in C?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, operator-precedence

a is a pointer to structure and b is the structure

```
a++ -> b
```

The order of evalution of above code will be

```
((a++) -> b)
```

or

```
(a -> b) ++
```

Comment: `(a -> b) ++` means something completely different from `a++ -> b`.

Comment: Why would the increment suddenly change to affect b?

Comment: well between a and b,  -> is the highest precedence operator right

Comment: Order of evaluation and precedence are not the same thing at all. Don't mix them together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As *postfix increment* and the *pointer to member operator* have exactly the same *precedence*, the *associativity* of the two operators comes into play. Both are left to right.

Hence

```
a++ -> b
```

is evaluated as

```
(a++) -> b
```

This means that the `->` applies to the previous value of the pointer `a`, and `a` is incremented with the normal rules - to be accomplished sometime before the statement completes execution.

(One for the pub quiz, the *prefix increment* has a lower precedence than `->`).

Comment: This: *"a is incremented [...] once the expression completes"* is not 100% accurate. `a` can be incremented at any time between the previous and next sequence point.

Comment: How does associativity come into play for this case? The expression is unambiguous. There is no other way to parse even if associativity is reversed.

Comment: @pmg: Yes you're correct: I've nicked the text from the footnote on the operator precedence table stuck to the wall in my office.

Comment: Here is a nice table of the C operator precedence which contains also the associativity: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: what will be the value of a++, since it is a pointer to a structure, incrementing it would make pointer to skip the entire structure, and it will be a wild pointer.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.3 Structure and union members)

> 4 **A postfix expression** followed by the -> operator and an
>   identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The
>   value is that of the named member of the object to which the first
>   expression points, and is an lvalue.96) If the first expression is a
>   pointer to a qualified type, the result has the so-qualified version
>   of the type of the designated member.

In this expression

```
a++ -> b
```

`a++` is a postfix expression. So you may write it like

```
( a++ ) -> b
```

This expression yields the value of the data member `b` of the object pointed to by the value of the pointer `a`  before its increment.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    struct A
    {
        int b;
    } pair[] = { { 1 }, { 2 } };

    struct A *a = pair;

    printf("%d\n", a++->b);
    printf("%d\n", a++->b);

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1
2
```